# Not getting any response of cross-domain AJAX call on iOS device

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, phonegap-build

I am not getting any response of cross-domain AJAX call in safari browser and ios device.

Sample Code:

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'GET',                                // Method use to call url
         url: 'http://someurl/?callback=?',          // Different domain
         jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallBack',              // Call server's function which inturns return values
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
         dataType: 'jsonp',                          // Mention datatype as JSONP for cross-domain call
         cache: false,
         async: false,
         timeout: 10000,                             
         success: function(data)
         {
            alert('Success');
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
         {
            alert('Error');
         }
```

Above code gives me alert - 'Error' whereas it should take me to success function.

Comment: Is your server actually JSONP?

Comment: Obviously something is not crossing right. Have you tried running it in Saffari, changing User Agent to iOS4.3 and watching the console when it loads?

Comment: "async: false," is impossible with a JSONP call

Comment: @ SpYk3HH - I tried but didn't get anything in console

Comment: @ epascarello - But how come it is working on android device? The only problem is on ios device

Comment: Modified error function - error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  alert('Error-'+JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
       }  gives me alert Error-{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

Comment: @ SLaks - I didn't get you friend. I am getting response from server in android device.